# How to convert a more than 1 doc file in a folder into text file using java.can u modify this code

Tags: java

Code for one separate file:

```
import java.io.*; 
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.extractor.XWPFWordExtractor; 
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument; 

    public class ReadDocFile { 
        public static void main(String[] args) { 
            File file = null; 

            try { 
                // Read the Doc/DOCx file 
                file = new File("document"); 
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath()); 
                XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(fis); 
                XWPFWordExtractor ex = new XWPFWordExtractor(doc); 
                String text = ex.getText(); 

                //write the text in text file 
                File fil = new File("D:\\wordtotextoutput\\java1new.txt"); 
                Writer output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fil)); 
                output.write(text); 
                output.close(); 
            } catch (Exception exep) { 
            } 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: What rule do you want to apply with each document ?  you want to append them all one after the other in your text file ?  
The input documents are text also ?

Comment: You know, you can use `java.io.renameTo` to *move* and rename a file.  (Though there isn't a mechanism that I know of to simply copy a file, other than using `Runtime.exec`.)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following...

```
public void convertFiles(String folderpath){
    File folder = new File(folderpath);
    for (File file: folder.listFiles()){
        if (!file.isDirectory()){
            //call your existing method here for `folder`
        }
        else{
            //not sure if you want to handle files in subdirectories
        }
    }
}
```